# amsynth and the virtual keyboard

Tags: audio

I'm using amsynth on the Pi, which works well, but I can't get the virtual keyboard to work. As directed by the FAQ (https://code.google.com/p/amsynth/wiki/FAQs) I've installed vkeybd:

```
apt-get install vkeybd
```

...and it runs from the terminal (or menu).

I've also configured amsynth to use MIDI: ALSA and Audio: ALSA, restarted amsynth, but the Virtual Keyboard menu item continues to be greyed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the FAQ states, the Virtual Keyboard menu item just launchs vkeybd, and connect it to amSynth. We can do this through other ways:

1. Launch `vkeybd`;
2. connect it to `amSynth`:

   - via `QJackctl`: open the connexions window, ALSA tab, select vkeybd on the left and amSynth on the right and click connect;
   - with `aconnect`: in aterminal, type `aconnect -i`:

     > client 0: 'System' [type=noyau]
     >      0 'Timer           '
     >      1 'Announce        '
     >   client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=noyau]
     >      0 'Midi Through Port-0'
     >   client 129: 'amSynth' [type=utilisateur]
     >      1 'amSynth MIDI OUT'
     >   client 130: 'VMPK Output' [type=utilisateur]
     >      0 'VMPK Output     '
     >   client 132: 'Virtual Keyboard' [type=utilisateur]
     >      0 'Virtual Keyboard'

     Now, `aconnect -o`:

     > client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=noyau]
     >      0 'Midi Through Port-0'
     >   client 129: 'amSynth' [type=utilisateur]
     >      0 'amSynth MIDI IN '
     >   client 131: 'VMPK Input' [type=utilisateur]
     >      0 'VMPK Input

   And we can connect them with `aconnect 132 129`

Bonus: you can automate it:

`` aconnect `aconnect -i | grep 'Virtual Keyboard' | grep client | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d ':' -f 1` `aconnect -o | grep 'amSynth' | grep client | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | cut -d ':' -f 1` ``

Note that you can do this with the `QJackctl` Patchbay too.